# DropBox Chooser Example issue

Tags: android, dropbox

I now have the ChooserExample program that comes with dropbox-android-chooser-sdk-1.0 working from level 10 up through 19.

Regardless of the kind of link I choose (preview or direct) the URL's it produces are huge long.  Looks like 75 characters or more.[image]

But on my PC, if I pick up the public link on that same dropbox picture it's much shorter:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39662979/500Error.png

Why can't the chooser produce such a nice short link?
Thanks,
Dean

Comment: when i press choose button it every time suggest me to download dropbox. How to solve this ? can u help me? How can I get result like you when press choose button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that the Chooser returns a different kind of link. It's the same kind of link as used for the shared link feature in the rest of Dropbox:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/167

It is also is a bit more configurable:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

The /u/ link you mentioned is a link from the old Public folder:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/16

(To be clear, this is referring to the main /s/ link from the screenshot. The thumbnail links are longer yet, as they are yet another kind of link with different properties.)

Comment: Sorry. My post is bogus.  The "Link" (ending in dl=0) is short.  I was confused by the sized pictures.